# Error when using StreamProvider and StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am trying to use StreamProvider and StreamBuilder to pull data from firestore into my app with the code below. I am getting the error "streamusers and "userslist" are not defined as well as "testuser" is not a type. Here is a picture of my firestore database[firestore setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeV9D.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeV9D.png)

does anyone know how I can fix this so that it pulls the data from firestore and updates dynamically when new users are added?

Main.dart:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final db = DatabaseService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);
    bool loggedIn = user != null;

    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    StreamProvider<List<User>>.value(
      value: db.streamUsers(user),
      child: UsersList(),
    ),

    StreamBuilder<TestUser>(
      stream: db.streamTestUser(user.uid),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        var user = snapshot.data;

        if (user != null) {
            return Stack(...
```

I also have my db.dart file as so:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  Future<User> getUser(String id) async {
    var snap = await _db.collection('users').document(id).get();

    return User.fromMap(snap.data);
  }

    Stream<User> streamTestUser(String id) {
      return _db
          .collection('users')
          .document(id)
          .snapshots()
          .map((snap) => User.fromMap(snap.data));
    }

}
```

And finally my user_model.dart file:

```
class User {

  final String name;
  final String photourl;
  final int totalquestions;

  User({this.name, this.photourl, this.totalquestions});

  factory User.fromMap(Map data) {
    return User(
      name: data['name'] ?? '',
      photourl: data['photourl'] ?? '',
      totalquestions: data['totalquestions'] ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well i cant find the methode streamUsers(user) In DatabaseService

Comment: Adn you dont have a model of testuser this is why it says "testuser" is not a type . your function should be StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: db.streamTestUser(user.uid),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        var user = snapshot.data;

        if (user != null) {
            return Stack(...

Comment: @Mohamedhassankadri thank you, but this is still giving me the error: error: The argument type 'Stream<User> can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<User> (argument_type_not_assignable at [flutter_appprofilescreenv1] lib/main.dart:91)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Builder` inside `StreamProvider` instead of `StreamBuilder`.
Mine is working using this approach.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

  return StreamProvider<User>.value(
    value: db.getUser(user?.uid),
    catchError: (_, __) => null,
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        ///Passing UserData Down the Builder
        var _userSnapshot = Provider.of<UserData>(context);

        ///Check UserData Availability
        if (_userSnapshot == null) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('User Empty'),
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_userSnapshot?.name),
                Text(_userSnapshot?.photourl),
                Text(_userSnapshot?.totalquestions),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```